# Accessing arrays and using for each loop php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need some help with some code I am working on. The code is kinda of a mail merge type of system that uses an xml document, and swaps out some words for variables with php.

I am building an array of data, shown below.

```
$emaillist = array(
                array('fname'            => 'Brad',
                     'lname'            => 'B',
                     'recipient'        => 'BB@gmail.com'),  

                array('fname'            => 'Josh',
                     'lname'            => 'M',
                     'recipient'        => 'JM@gmail.com'),

                array('fname'            => 'Patrick',
                     'lname'            => 'P',
                     'recipient'        => 'PP@gmail.com'),

                array('fname'            => 'Dave',
                     'lname'            => 'J',
                     'recipient'        => 'DJ@hotmail.com'));
```

I then create a foreach loop, where I want lots of bits of code run for each person within the dataset, one thing that I am trying to do is swap replace some strings using str_replace(). How would I go about accessing the value for the first name for each person in the foreach.

I think that to access it outside of a loop it would be like $data[0]['fname'] but obviously this cannot be done in the foreach.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: looking for `foreach ($emaillist as $key => $value) {
  echo $value['fname'];
}`?? result is `BradJoshPatrickDave` ??

Comment: That will work @devpro, no need to cast the `$key` though and `$value` could be more explicit in this example, such as `foreach($emaillist as $recipient)`

Comment: the way you wanted to use the data is possible too but with a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop

Comment: @Jackhardcastle: actually i am using Sublime , just copy and paste the result :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `foreach` loop will do the trick. However if you want to amend any of the items in the array you are processing you have to remember to pass the array to the foreach loop as a reference i.e. `&$emaillist` like this

```
<?php
$emaillist = array(
                array('fname'            => 'Brad',
                     'lname'            => 'B',
                     'recipient'        => 'BB@gmail.com'),  

                array('fname'            => 'Josh',
                     'lname'            => 'M',
                     'recipient'        => 'JM@gmail.com'),

                array('fname'            => 'Patrick',
                     'lname'            => 'P',
                     'recipient'        => 'PP@gmail.com'),

                array('fname'            => 'Dave',
                     'lname'            => 'J',
                     'recipient'        => 'DJ@hotmail.com'));

foreach ($emaillist as &$person) {
    // silly example, amends any a charackter to xxx
    $person['fname'] = str_replace('a', 'xxx', $person['fname']);  
}

print_r($emaillist);
```

RESULTS:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Brxxxd
            [lname] => B
            [recipient] => BB@gmail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Josh
            [lname] => M
            [recipient] => JM@gmail.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Pxxxtrick
            [lname] => P
            [recipient] => PP@gmail.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Dxxxve
            [lname] => J
            [recipient] => DJ@hotmail.com
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

check this, I have created new array using `$emaillist` array. While generating that array you can perform `str_replece` function as I mentioned.

```
$data = array();
foreach($emaillist as $key=>$row){
        $data[$key]['fname'] =  $row['fname']; // add str_replace(search, replace, $row['fname'])
        $data[$key]['lname'] = $row['lname'];
        $data[$key]['recipient'] = $row['recipient'];

}
```

Comment: If you want to amend an answer, you can delete it, then edit it, then undelete it. You dont need to create a new answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for your advice, I will follow that.